# Store datetime without seconds using SQL in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I created this function below in PHP to insert some ticker details in database.  I'd like to store a datetime field in database without seconds because that json data is updated every minute.

```
function insert(){

        $jsonArray = json_decode(self::getTicker(), true);

        var_dump($jsonArray);

        foreach ($jsonArray as $value) {
            $high = $value['high'];
            $low = $value['low'];
            $last = $value['last'];
            $buy = $value["buy"];
            $sell = $value['sell'];
            $date = $value['date'];
            $vol = $value['vol'];
        }
        $dateF = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `ticker_history`
        (`ticker_history_high`, 
        `ticker_history_low`, 
        `ticker_history_vol`, 
        `ticker_history_last`, 
        `ticker_history_buy`, 
        `ticker_history_sell`,
        `ticker_history_date`)
        VALUES 
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("dddddss", $high,$low,$vol,$last,$buy,$sell,$dateF);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
                // ticker successfully inserted
            return  print_r(TICKER_CREATED_SUCCESSFULLY);

        } else{
            return print_r(TICKER_CREATE_FAILED);
        }
}
```

Comment: Change `gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $date);` to `gmdate("Y-m-d H:i", $date);` ?

Comment: A `DATETIME` field in the database *has* seconds in it - it's part of the datatype ... you can, of course, just format your date to `Y-m-d H:i:00` when entering it into the database if you don't need seconds.

Comment: I tried to do that, but it stores the data with :00 secs

Comment: Why is that a problem? Just because it's got `00` seconds in the database, doesn't mean your application has to do anything with it.

Comment: @MateusMascarenhas you can change it in your insert query check my answer

Comment: Because I'd like to pass into function just datetime without secs into my function when I fetch that data in db.

Comment: Ye-es but - it *really* shouldn't matter that the database is holding a value of `00` for seconds... you want to reformat it when it comes out of the database? Fine `DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $db['date'])->format('Y-m-d H:i')` ... I'm really not seeing the problem.

Comment: As @CD001 states, just insert it with seconds as that is a date/time column structure and retrieve without: `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ticker_history_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') FROM ticker_history`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datetime column uses the structure Y-m-d H:i:s

It will always store seconds. However you can use PHP's DateTime class to format dates like so:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i'); // outputs 2017-08-18 17:05
```

When querying the DB, in the WHERE clause you can say:

```
...WHERE datecolumn = '".$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:00')."' etc
```

Example:

```
$date = new DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n"; // 2017-08-18 17:09:15
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:00')."\n"; // 2017-08-18 17:09:00
```

See it in action: https://3v4l.org/D47pA

Btw you can pass in your string into the DateTime constructor like

`new DateTime($row['datecolumn']);`

Answer (score 0):

Just change `$dateF` to  this :

```
gmdate('d-m-y H:i',strtotime($date)));
```

Or this in your SQL query :

```
DATE(date, '%Y-%M-%d %H:%i')
```

In MARIADB :

```
DATE_FORMAT(date, '%H:%i')
```

Comment: That's not going to altar the structure of MariaDBs `DATETIME` datatype though - it'll still end up as `Y-m-d H:i:00` in the database.

Comment: I tried to change that variable $dateF for this, but it doesn't work

Comment: @MateusMascarenhas the function i added work in MariaDbs ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()` -

```
$dateF = gmdate('g:ia', strtotime($date));
```

The `date() function` - `string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )` - where `$timestamp` is to be an integer Unix timestamp.

Comment: This would mean changing the datatype from `DATETIME` to `INT(10) unsigned` ... and makes life tricky if you want to make use of the database's native date manipulation functions (as no longer a date). In short - this is not a great idea.

Comment: No It does't do that but remove the seconds from timestamp. strtotime() in php, converts datetime to time()

Answer (score 0):

For straight MySQL/MariaDB solution, adapt this:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i");
+--------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i") |
+--------------------------------------+
| 2017-08-21 21:35                     |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Note: the value stored in the table will be a correct `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` of `2017-08-21 21:35:00`.

This approach is less coding than computing the date in PHP.